# Variable for unique ids in JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript, function, loops, onclick

I have an onclick event called in a PHP `foreach` loop for several items whose author name I need to click. Only one name was getting generated, so I know that I must have a unique id for each HTML element. I already have a variable `$objkey` for a counter used in the loop so I appended it to the id.

```
<?php
//This is the item that appears in the loop. 
//Currently, clicking on each one that is generated only generates the first author name
//The correct author as passed by PHP displays in the loop.
//$closest is the value of the author's name.
echo 'Click name to add <span><button id="closest' . $objkey . '"  onClick="setAuthor()">' . $closest . '</button></span><br />';
?>
```

I have done a `print_r('$objkey);` and the appropriate value for the counter is getting passed along.

I want the value of this button element `$closest` to be passed to an input field. I have appended the variable to both the input's id and name elements (not sure if that helps) (**UPDATE**: There is an input field for each of the authors that needs to get the value):

```
<?php 
echo '<input id="author_name' . $objkey . '"  type="text" name="author_name' . $objkey .  '" value="' . $author . '" />'; 
?>
```

Where I'm stuck is with my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function setAuthor() {
var author = document.getElementById("closest").innerHTML;
window.alert(author);
document.forms["myform"].elements["author_name"].value = author; }</script>
```

How do I create a variable in the function for the unique ids so that each looped item generates distinct names?

Comment: Where is there a loop in the code?

Comment: You'd be generating `closest1`, `closest2`, etc..., but looking for `closest`

Comment: Right, I don't know how to write looking for "closest1, closest2" into the function

Comment: Just do `onClick="setAuthor(this)"` and change the signature of the function to `function setAuthor(element) {`, then do `var author = element.innerHTML`

Comment: Yep, that works. But it enters each name into the same input element. I have edited the original post to show that each author has an input field associated with it. 

Would I add a counter in the function to assign the function?

Comment: I don't understand what your last comment is asking.

Comment: Note that the onclick event isn't *called* in PHP. PHP generates HTML with an inline binding, but PHP is entirely agnostic about client-side events.

Comment: [`<br/>`](http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/#br) is rarely [semantic](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/5-site-structure/2-semantic-markup.html); use something more appropriate, such as a paragraph or [list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html) element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to pass `this` to the the setAuthor function:

```
<?php
//This is the item that appears in the loop. 
//Currently, clicking on each one that is generated only generates the first author name
//The correct author as passed by PHP displays in the loop.
//$closest is the value of the author's name.
echo "Click name to add <button id='closest_{$objkey}' onClick='setAuthor(this)'>{$closest}</button><br/>";
?>
```

With this approach, you can access the element within `setAuthor`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setAuthor(el) {
    var author = el.innerHTML,
        id = el.id.replace(/^closest_/, '');
    if (console) {
        console.log(author);
    }
    document.forms["myform"].elements["author_name_" + id].value = author;
}
</script>
```

However, you shouldn't set `onclick` inline and for each element. You should use an event registration function.

Comment: I missed those edits @outis, thanks. I see that the ID is getting passed, but the author value is not finding its way to the input fields. Do I need to change the id for the input field? Like to:
`<input class="authors" id="author_name_{$objkey}"  type="text" name="author_name" value="' . $author . '" />';`

Comment: I removed the curly braces around $objkey and replaced it as follows:
`id="author_name_' . $objkey . '" type="text" name="author_name" value="' . $author . '" />';`
This enables the first name to be saved to the associated input field, but none of the other names, when clicked, populate any inputs. Getting closer.

Comment: Eureka! the form element needed to be unique, too. I did the same approach as for the input element for the form id:
 echo '<form id="myform_' . $objkey . '">';
The id is generated in the above code.
`document.forms["myform_"+id].elements["auth_"+id].value = author;`
Thanks for all of the help